# Count pandas DataFrame entries by description

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset (`DataFrame`) with transactions and a description for every transaction.
Additional every transaction has a value.

How can count the number of transactions per description and how can I sum up all values for one description.

I am sure, this was asked before, but I am not sure what I am looking for...
So just point me to the function names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupby.count()

```
DataFrame.groupby(['description']).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use  `groupby` and `agg` with 'size' and 'sum'.  Look at [pandas split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from seaborn import load_dataset

tips = load_dataset('tips')
df_out = tips.groupby('time')['total_bill'].agg(['size', 'sum'])
df_out
```

Output:

```
        size      sum
time                 
Lunch     68  1167.47
Dinner   176  3660.30
```